# postgres aws connect error in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

[image]

As the picture shows, I got that error thousands times.

I'm new to postgresql and aws, but I did everything that AWS instructed.

I made Security Group correctly. (inbound rules : postgreSQL, TCP, 5432, (Source: I put anywhere and my IP and custom. I tried everything I could do))

I typed the endpoint of RDS correctly as well.

Comment: look for pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf file is it accepting all external connection or not parameter is `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: how can I find the file 'pb_hba.conf, postgresql.conf'?? I don't know. ((

Comment: ask your database `SHOW config_file;`

Comment: I typed 'show config_file' and this showed up "/Users/mac/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6/postgresql.conf"

Comment: finally I opened postgresql.conf

Comment: it's too long.. what should I do here??

Comment: look for `listen_addresses` parameter if it is commented with `#`, then remove the `#` and change it `listen_addresses = '*'`

Comment: #listen_addresses = 'localhost'  # what IP address(es) to listen on;

Comment: It is written like that

Comment: remove the `#` and change it with `listen_addresses = '*'` and then restart the database

Comment: #listen_addresses = '*' is correct in postgresql.conf?

Comment: It doesn't work. the same error showed up

Comment: I told you to remove the `#` sign from the line and restart the Data base then it will work

Comment: if you don't mind please, let me know your email, I'd like to send my config files if it is needed. ((((

Comment: its against community's ethics and value

Comment: I did it. but same error

Comment: listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -
listen_addresses = '*'# what IP address(es) to listen on;
     # comma-separated list of addresses;
     # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
     # (change requires restart)

Comment: did you restart the service of your database and moreover I can't  c the `'*'` in the file and one more thing you need to uncomment `#port = 5432 ` too just replace the `#`

Comment: Okay. I'm going to trily it again when I get home. Thanks any way )) keep answering me plz~~~

Comment: For troubleshooting purpose you might want to change your security group inbound rules in RDS to All traffic and see if it works.